# ¿como obtener la diferencia de fecha expresada en días, horas y minutos en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

por ejemplo, entre esta dos fechas.

fechainicio:2017-08-14 15:00:00
fechatermino: 2017-08-15 17:30:00
quisiera obtenerlo en este formato como resultado:

1 día, 2 horas y 30 minutos,

**¿como podría obtenerlo?**

He intentado con DATEDIFF, pero solo me da la diferencia en dias.

Tambien he intentado usar el TIMESTAMPDIFF, pero solo me da el total del tiempo que le indico,(dia,hora, segundo),

La idea es poder obtenerlo en el formato que indique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no hay una función especifica que te devuelva ese resultado, tendrías que hacer unos cálculos con los valores que te devuelve TIMESTAMPDIFF, y concatenar los resultados de acuerdo con tus necesidades.

```
SET @inicio = '2017-08-14 15:00:00';
SET @fin = '2017-08-15 17:30:00';

SELECT CONCAT( 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @inicio, @fin), ' dias, ', 
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, @inicio, @fin), 24), ' horas y ', 
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @inicio, @fin), 60), ' minutos ' 
)
```